# swift multilpe pickerView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uipickerview

I can't seem to get all of my three options to appear when I populate my picker view.  It will only give me the last selected column result.

```
import UIKit

class ViewThree: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sizePicker: UIPickerView!

    var wheelContents:[[String]] = []
    var one = ["1", "2"]
    var two = ["A", "B", "C"]
    var three = ["X", "Y"]

    @IBOutlet var sparLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        wheelContents = [one, two, three]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return wheelContents.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return wheelContents[component].count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return wheelContents[component][row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        var wheel = wheelContents[component][row]
        sparLabel.text = "\(wheel)"
    }
}
```

The problem is I'm not sure what to put in my didSelectRow {}
If I generate them as individual results it seems to crash whenever I select the 3rd option of the three row column.
If I leave it as it is it only gives the last selected column and row.
I'd like it to display in one label like "1CY".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = ""

for var i = 0; i < wheelContents.count; i++
{
    let selectedRow = pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(i) //get selected row in component
    let value = wheelContents[i][selectedRow] //get displayed value in component
    result += value + " "
}

sparLabel.text = result
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work. Although I've no idea how.  Out of interest and for future reference, how would I make it so it displayed with a space between outputs so "1 C Y"?  Thanks again.

Comment: That's absolutely perfect.  Many thanks for your help ChikabuZ!